# Problemas con el uso de arreglos en C#

Tags: c#, array, visual-studio, bucles

Se me pide realizar el código del siguiente encabezado:

Escriba un programa en C# que almacene en un arreglo n calificaciones de la asignatura de Programación Orientada a Objetos. El programa debe imprimir la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados de dicha asignatura.

El problema es que me da resultados a veces erróneos y no se a que se deba realmente, adjuntare imágenes de cuando me da esos resultados, la primero que quería hacer era meter el arreglo con las calificaciones en otro arreglo en el cual se realizaría el promedio de cada estudiante sin embargo siempre daba respuestas incorrectas ya que tomaba cada nota como si fuera un estudiante y eso se reflejaba en la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados por ej ingresaba que el primer estudiante tendrá 3 notas que son 60, 60 y 50 la respuesta en consola era de 2 aprobados y 1 reprobado cosa que estaba mal ya que solo se ingreso notas para un estudiante y estaba realizando un promedio para cada nota, me di por vencido y cambie por hacerlo de la manera convencional en meterlo en una variable int que no fuera un arreglo, apreciaría que me ayudaran a poder solucionar y entender el error de mi código por favor.

Les dejo el codigo que llevo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace n_calificaciones
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] calificaciones=null;//arreglo en el que se almacenara cada nota
            /*int[] suma= null;*/
            int n_cal = 0, i=0, cont_apro = 0, cont_repro = 0, est = 0, suma=0, prom=0;
            char opcion = 's';
               
            while(opcion == 's'){// ciclo que repitara hasta que se ingrese un caracter diferente de s

                 Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de notas del estudiante {0}: ", est+=1);
                n_cal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // numero de calificaciones que tendra cada estudiante

                calificaciones = new int[n_cal];// inicializacion del arreglo que tendra el tamaño ingresado de la variable n_cal

                /*suma = new int[n_cal];*/

                for(i=0;i<n_cal;i++){//ciclo que recorrera hasta el numero de notas ingresadas por cada estudiante hasta que no

                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la nota {0}", i+1);
                    calificaciones[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//cada nota que se ingresa se almacena en el arreglo


                }

                for (i = 0; i < n_cal; i++)//ciclo para recorrer el arreglo
                {

                    suma += calificaciones[i]; //operaciones para realizar el promedio de las notas de cada estudiante 

                    prom = suma / n_cal;

                }

                if (prom >= 60)// condicion para saber la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados segun su promedio 
                {

                    cont_apro++;//contador que contabiliza la cantidad de aprobados

                }
                else
                {

                    cont_repro++;//contador que contabiliza la cantidad de reprobados 

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Desea seguir ingresando mas datos (S/N)?");
                opcion = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            
           /* Console.WriteLine(" " + calificaciones[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(" " + calificaciones[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(" " + calificaciones[2]);*/

            Console.WriteLine("\nNumeros de aprobados: " + cont_apro);
            Console.WriteLine("Numeros de reprobados " + cont_repro);

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: Imagen 1]

Como pueden ver estoy ingresando notas para dos estudiantes y la respuesta deberia ser de 2 reprobados pero muestra 1 aprobado y 1 reprobado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay un boton editar abajo de tu pregunta...

Comment: Un estudiante está suspenso cuando su promedio de notas es menor a 60 y aprobado cuando du promedio de notas es mayor o igual a 60?

Comment: Por otra parte cuales son los datos que debe tener un estudiante?

Comment: Así es, si el promedio de notas de cada estudiante es mayor igual a 60 esta aprobado, caso contrario esta reprobado.

Comment: En la descripción del problema, en ningún lugar dice que haya que hacer promedios. ¿diste la descripción completa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que algunas variables deberían estar dentro del ciclo para que se re-inicializen. Adicional a eso , para este caso es preferible usar el do-while y como consejo revise la validación de la entrada del usuario, ya que este código no valida si el dato ingresado es un null o una letra, si se ingresa un valor null o algo que no sea un número va a dar un error.

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                char opcion = 's';// ciclo que repitara hasta que se ingrese un caracter diferente de s
    
                int cont_apro = 0, cont_repro = 0;
                do
                {
                    int n_cal = 0, est = 0, suma = 0, prom = 0;
                    int[] calificaciones = null;//arreglo en el que se almacenara cada nota
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de notas del estudiante {0}: ", est += 1);
                   
                    n_cal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // numero de calificaciones que tendra cada estudiante
    
                    calificaciones = new int[n_cal];// inicializacion del arreglo que tendra el tamaño ingresado de la variable n_cal
    
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < n_cal; i++)
                    {//ciclo que recorrera hasta el numero de notas ingresadas por cada estudiante hasta que no
    
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la nota {0}", i + 1);
                        calificaciones[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//cada nota que se ingresa se almacena en el arreglo
    
    
                    }
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < n_cal; i++)//ciclo para recorrer el arreglo
                    {
    
                        suma += calificaciones[i]; //operaciones para realizar el promedio de las notas de cada estudiante 
    
                    }
                    prom = suma / n_cal;
    
                    if (prom >= 60)// condicion para saber la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados segun su promedio 
                    {
    
                        cont_apro++;//contador que contabiliza la cantidad de aprobados
    
                    }
                    else
                    {
    
                        cont_repro++;//contador que contabiliza la cantidad de reprobados 
    
                    }
    
    
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Desea seguir ingresando mas datos (S/N)?");
                    opcion = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    
                } while (opcion == 's');
    
                Console.WriteLine("\nNumeros de aprobados: " + cont_apro);
                Console.WriteLine("Numeros de reprobados " + cont_repro);
    
                Console.Read();
    
            }
        }
```